# How can I modify an XML file in place using Perl's XML::Twig?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am using Perl and [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig). I have made some changes in the XML file( changing the values of the tags). But I cannot write it in the same XML file. If I use `parsefile_inplace()` the whole XML file got empty. Please find the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(
        pretty_print => 'indented',
        twig_handlers => {
            jdk => sub{ 
            $_->set_text( 'JDK 1.8.0_40' )
            },
            },
        );
$twig->parsefile_inplace( 'nightly.xml', 'bak.*' );
$twig->flush;
```

Part of XML file:

```
<jdk>JDK 1.7.0_40</jdk>
```

If I use flush command it gives the desired output on cmd.

If I use `parsefile_inplace` command it is emptying the `nightly.xml`.

If I just use `parsefile` the original file is left intact without changing the value i want to change.

My requirement is to edit the value and save it in the same file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what [the documentation for `parsefile_inplace`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#parsefile_inplace-file-optional_extension) says:

> `parsefile_inplace ( $file, $optional_extension)`
>
> Parse and update a file "in place". It does this by creating a temp file, ***selecting it as the default for `print()` statements*** (and methods), then parsing the input file. If the parsing is successful, then the temp file is moved to replace the input file.
>
> If an extension is given then the original file is backed-up (the rules for the extension are the same as the rule for the `-i` option in `perl`). (*emphasis mine*)

I do not see any print statements in your code.

Here is one way to do it, with small changes to your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig= XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    twig_roots => {
        jdk => sub{
            my ($t, $jdk) = @_;
            $jdk->set_text( 'JDK 1.8.0_40' );
            $jdk->print;
            $jdk->purge;
            return;
        },
    },
    twig_print_outside_roots => 1,
);

$twig->parsefile_inplace( 'nightly.xml', '.bak' );
$twig->flush;
```

Comment: oh yeah, i didnt use print statement.
It worked . Thank you @Sinan Unur